# Is it mandatory to get networking-multicast entitlement for local network access to support iOS 14?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios14

My app is using 2 broadcast services (_xxx-xx-xxx._tcp, _xxx._tcp) to search for the devices in the network. For this, do I need to add the **`networking-multicast entitlement`** for the app?

Currently, I have added the services in `NSBonjourServices` and `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription` and is working fine.

In the sample tutorial provided by apple

> https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10110/

It is instructed to request for entitlement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find answer for your question in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663875

There are also current exceptions mentioned.